# Access database design in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-migration

We have 52 MS Access databases and each database has 4 tables. The total data in our databases is around 5 million. Now we are planning to move to SQL Server. We have designed our new database which will be an SQL Server database with approximately 60 tables.

My question is - how will we integrate the 52 Access databases into one SQL Server database?
Is it possible, or we would have to create 52 database in SQL Server too, in order to migrate our data? these 52 databases are interrelated with each other having same structure in access?

Comment: What kind of data are you handling? Why dozens of DBs with 4 tables each? Is it the same table data? The same table layout? It's impossible to answer without getting additional info.

Comment: To address your question, though, it's completely possible to have 52 databases in one SQL Server instance. In fact, you can have up to 32.767 databases per instance if you'd need: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: Basically there are 52 countries and for each country their is one database, in which we have currently 4 tables which are Doctor, Project, Contract, Institution. the table have same layout in all databases.

Comment: What would be your argument to keep the databases separated? What about merging them into a single database? 

Are you trying to have a seamless migration, or ease of use down the road? If you have the manpower and resources to do so, I'd really advise you to try and come up with a solution where you end up with a single database, with just a small amount of tables. I.e. add country details to the tables and then merge all data into that. That way, if you ever need to change the table structure, you'd do it once, rather than 52 times.

Comment: It'd also be easier to administrate. However, it'd require more work right now to box all the data into the new structure.

Comment: Thanks SChmitzIT ,  in our new design in sql we are adding separate table which will hold country details. Will it be then possible to Migrate all countries database into one big sql database. What will be the best way?

Comment: I'd probably do for a design where you add a country table, and then a countryID to the existing tables. During the migration, you populate the countryID field with the hardcoded ID for the country you're importing. I.e. if US has ID1, you simply set CountryID to 1 for every record. IT'd be pretty straight-forward really. 

Ity'd have the additional benefit it would allow you to later on partition the data if you'd need.

Comment: as suggested, add one column of country, and you thus not need 50 instances of the same database with all the costs + time of maintianing that many databases. (this is called normlizing your data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was you (and I'm not, but if I was...) I would load all of that data into 4 tables.  Just append all the data from each Access database into one table.  Doctor, Project, Contract, Institution.  However, as I'm appending each database, I would add a new field to each table; Country.  Then, when you append the data for England to the tables, you also populate the Country field of that table with "England".  Etc... with all your countries.

Now, when it comes time to access the data, you can force certain users to only be able to see the data for England, and certain other people to only see the data for Spain, etc...  This way, those 4 tables can house **all** of your data, and you can still filter by any country you like.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical point of view, there's no problem in creating only one SQL Server database, containing all 52 * 4 tables from the MS Access databases. SQL Server provides various options for logically separating your objects, for example by using Schemas. But then again, if you decide to create separate databases, you still have the ability to write queries across databases, even if the databases are not hosted on the same SQL Server instance (although there might be a performance penalty when writing queries across linked servers).

It's difficult to give a more precise answer with the limited detail in your question, but in most cases, a single database with multiple database schema (perhaps 1 schema for each MS access database) would probably be the best solution.

Now, for migrating the data from MS Access to SQL Server, you have various options. If you just need to perform a one-time migration, you could simply use the Import-Export wizard that comes with SQL Server. The wizard automatically creates the tables in the destination database for you, and it also lets you save SSIS-packages that you can use to migrate the data again.